# Why proc_read(), which is a function related to /proc in Linux, is called "repeatedly" until it returns 0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel-module

In the book *Operating System Concepts*, it designs a kernel module, the module seems to create an additional entry named hello in the /proc file system in Linux, the module code is shown below, then it uses `cat /proc/hello` command, it says "***Each time the /proc/hello file is read, the proc_read() function is called repeatedly until it returns 0***", I can't understand why proc_read() is called **repeatedly**, also I don't know who is the caller of the function proc_read().

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 128
#define PROC_NAME "hello"

ssize_t proc_read(struct file *file, char _user *usr_buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos);
static struct file_operations proc_ops = {
.owner = THIS MODULE,
.read = proc_read,
};

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int proc_init(void)
{
 /* creates the /proc/hello entry */
 proc_create(PROC_NAME, 0666, NULL, &proc_ops);
 return 0;
}

/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void proc_exit(void)
{
 /* removes the /proc/hello entry */
 remove_proc_entry(PROC_NAME, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Call repeatedly from user space until all the data is read.

Comment: The caller of `proc_read` is clearly your `cat` process, via a `read` syscall and a vfs method table.